# Boolean variable update behaving weirdly in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, react-native, boolean

I am running a simple update, which included a couple boolean variables, but for some reason they seem to be flipped.

```
UPDATE table SET booleanVar=? WHERE id=XX, [booleanVar]
```

If `booleanVar` is true, it actually seems to set it to 0, and to 1 if `booleanVar` is false. I have managed to make my code work by just changing [booleanVar] to [!booleanVar], but I can't figure out why it is doing this in the first place.

Comment: `UPDATE table SET booleanVar=? WHERE id=XX, [booleanVar]` is not a valid SQL statement. Please make an example that is valid, or at least make explicit where you are using meta-variables. What is `XX`? What is `[booleanVar]`?

Comment: @Amadan

Sorry this is in react native so its a bit different. Below is a snippet after I added the !, which works, but I'm not sure why

`tx.executeSql(
        "UPDATE table SET name=?, settingEnable=? WHERE id=?",
        [
          updatedData.name,
          !updatedData.settingEnable,
          itemId
        ]`